# About hash table

Tags: hashmap, hashtable, hash

A hash function h maps 16-bit inputs to 8-bit hash values. What is the largest k such that in any set of
1,000 inputs, there are at least k inputs that h maps to the same hash value?

I think k should be 3. Because 1000/256=3.~
However the answer key is 4. It is a GRE exam so I guess its answer is correct. Could any one help me explain it?

Comment: @MitchWheat, nah, preparing for the exam

Answer (score 1):

It is 4 because you need to round *up* here. There are 256 possible hash outputs; if you get at most 3 times each output value, then you have at most 256*3 = 768 inputs. So the answer is 1000/256, *rounded up*, hence 4.

Comment: LoL, it seems it is my English issue. Thanks